# Use of javascript function inside if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Can someone explain how the following if statement works. Inside the if statement there is a test for function addFieldToText, and its arguments. After this line the script jumps into the addFieldToText function

```
 if(!addFieldToText(refworksFieldMappingEntry.enterpriseCode, refworksFieldMappingEntry))
```

Is it basically saying if this function has not been called yet, then call it?
Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as that `if` statement is encountered, it:

- Calls the `addFieldToText` function passing `refworksFieldMappingEntry.enterpriseCode`, `refworksFieldMappingEntry` as arguments.
- If `addFieldToText` returns `false` based on those arguments value, then the if statement is executed.

If the `addFieldToText` was not prefixed with `!` (NOT operator) then `addFieldToText` would have to return a truthy value for the if statement to execute.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
const isNumberDivisibleBy2 = (num) => {
  return num % 2 === 0
}

if (!isNumberDivisibleBy2(9)) {
  console.log('number is NOT divisible by 2')
} else {
  console.log('number is divisible by 2')
}
```